How to identify pin A1 of tiny DSBGA IC (TPS7A21)?
I have a DSBGA IC (TI TPS7A21) that measures only 0.622 x 0.622 mm. Here is the datasheet. The IC is sectioned into four quadrants. So far, so good, but:
How can I identify from the top view, what pin A1 is?
There is no mention of any marking for any pins in the datasheet.
On addendum-page 1, there is a mention of device marking, but it says nothing about orientation relative to pins (also, the IC's marking would be Z, which can be rotated 180° and would look the same).
Pack Materials-Page 1 has tape and reel information. There is a drawing (top?) of how the ICs are placed in the tape. Here, quadrant 1 holds pin A1.
Is this the only way of identifying where pin A1 is? Looking at the way it was placed in the reel and remembering that orientation?
I have several ICs that are not in the reel anymore, that I would like to identify...
Here you can see the surface of the IC under a microscope. I can't guarantee that it hasn't been rotated when peeling the tape open, this is just for illustrating what there is to see on the IC's surface...
As you can see, there are markings. It's hard to take a photo of, but it looks pretty much like a small 7 then Z and below the 7 there seems to be a dot.
Is there maybe some convention that I'm unaware of and that isn't mentioned in the datasheet? Does the dot simply mark pin A1? It's what my intuition would tell me.

The DieSizeBGA chips have A1 corner marked with a small square:
picture refused for some reason, see page 6

When zooming in on the picture I provided, you can see, that there is no small square on the IC's surface.

@XIII_, there is a small dot on your picture. Square or dot mark, it depends on particular equipment a chip maker uses, and per package specifications it indicates A1 ball. There is no "pin1", it is ball grid array, and pins are counted in a grid of coordinates, A1, A2, B1,B2, etc. It is not for IC datasheet, it is the package specifications.

I've accepted your answer. True, I kept mentioning a pin 1. I've edited this to A1.
Maybe it would be smart if you edited your answer as well, so it mentions that the dot which can be seen in the microscope picture indeed is the marking of pin A1.

On page 26 of the data sheet in the link you provided shows the marking for pin A1 on the top of the device (presumably laser marked). The bottom view shows the pin grid names typical for BGA devices (rows A & B, columns 1 & 2). The data sheet uses third angle projection which is common in the U.S. and U.K..

Sorry for getting technical, but page 26 shows shaded an area that is described as "PIN A1 INDEX AREA". It does not technically provide the marking for pin A1 on the IC surface.
So, what is that area? Is it the area that contains the marking? Which marking exactly? Please, take a look at the microscope picture I posted. Does the dot maybe indicate A1?

I want to highlight that there is no shaded area on the IC surface.

@XIII_ The mechanical drawing shows three views: top, side, bottom. If the drawing is third angle projection (not specifically stated on the drawing, but one can infer the projection by examining the top and side views), you can determine what the pins numbers are. In your image, the dot will be A1. If you need further confirmation, manufacturers usually have documents showing the orientation of the device in the tape for each package type.
